# EditText doesn't autoscroll on second entry

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `editText` field in my layout as :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dyces.teacher.app.MainActivity"> -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/snowcitblacker"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/nocovertranss"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:minWidth="450px"
    android:minHeight="450px"
    android:id="@+id/teachName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guess"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/guess" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play"
    android:layout_below="@+id/teachName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
    android:id="@+id/play"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pause"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
    android:id="@+id/pause"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
    android:id="@+id/stop"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:hint="Enter Guess Here"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/guess"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:textColor="#F0EEEE"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/guess"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

While running the app on my phone, when I tap on the `editText` field, the layout adjusts itself such that the `editText` field is right above the keyboard and visible. 
The problem is when I try to tap on the field again (after minimizing the keyboard), the layout doesn't adjust this time.

In the two pictures below, on the first screenshot , the "Enter Guess Here" is the hint for the `editText` field, but on the second screenshot, this field is now hidden by the keyboard. The second screenshot was taken after the keyboard was minimized and the field tapped on.

[image: "Enter Guess Here" is the hint for the <code>editText</code> field]

[image: As evident the field is now hidden by the keyboard]

Comment: are you using scrollview as root container?

Comment: can you show your full layout or the main viewgroup.

Comment: @RanjitPati Edited the question with the entire layout just now.

Comment: @IllegalArgument Let me see if that solves the thing. Any reason as to why that might be the cause?

Comment: @MayurMohan edittext and scrollview might conflict when there is focus on edittext <requestfocus> delete this. if cursor is on edittext and you try to scroll the scrollview then there might be problems in correct dispatching of keydown(just a guess1). I had this problem when the content fit perfectly in scrollview and it didnot need any scrolling

Comment: Try moving the XML code of button above that of edit text.. Also you have set edit text at the start of button, and in button you have set it below edit text. Have you tested it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not using `ScrollView` as the root container. If you will put your `RelativeLayout` inside a `ScrollView` then it should likely work.

Comment: No that's not the problem, because it does adjusts even with no scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use Scroll View, Put all your code inside scroll view and check for the output, thanks
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.dyces.teacher.app.MainActivity" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/snowcitblacker" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/teachName"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guess"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/guess"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:minHeight="450px"
                android:minWidth="450px"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/nocovertranss" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/teachName"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
                android:src="@drawable/play" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pause"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/play"
                android:src="@drawable/pause" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/stop"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play"
                android:src="@drawable/stop" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/guess"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/play"
                android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Enter Guess Here"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:minWidth="250dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/guess"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
                android:minWidth="250dp"
                android:text="Check"
                android:textColor="#F0EEEE" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tried it and the problem persists

Comment: Try to add following into your Activity's definition in the manifest file:

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"